# Rails strongbox decryption in resque process

Tags: ruby-on-rails, encryption, amazon-web-services, resque

I periodically run a long decryption process on data that was encrypted with public key encryption via the [strongbox gem](https://github.com/spikex/strongbox). The process decrypts some messages, and sends the no-longer secure data to the requesting party.

The decryption process now takes long enough in some cases that it should really be performed asynchronously. I want to handle that by passing the job to a [resque scheduler](https://github.com/resque/resque-scheduler).

The decryption password is coming from a web request - how can I securely pass the password to resque? (resque and web request are on different AWS instances). I don't want someone with access to the resque logs to have access to the password.

Answer (score 0):

### Filter Parameter:

Well you can definitely filter your parameter/password from log 
so everytime you log via `Resque` logger or `Rails` logger try to filter those parameter out

Imagine the basic code snippet to look like this

```
def filter
  @filter ||= ActionDispatch::Http::ParameterFilter.new(Rails.application.config.filter_parameters)
end

def filter_parameter(params)
  filter.filter params
end
```

Now every time you call your logger simple filter the parameter

```
[Rails | Resque].logger.info (filter_parameter(my_parameter))
```

This would solve the problem of anyone having access to `Resque` or `Rails` logger knowing the password

### Secure Redis Connection:

All though this might filter the params in log but the Resque/redis does contain the sensitive data in them

I believe what  max you do to prevent some one sniffing for password inside redis
is connect `redis` with a password .

they way you can do that is set a password in `redis.conf`

Inside redis.conf hunt for this line (uncomment it and set your password)

```
#requirepass [set your redis password)
```

and then connect to `Resque` using this `password` this will ensure that only the client that are aware of redis password are allowed to make a connection

## Resque-web :

Well apparently if you are using `resque-web` the data still might be available on the UI 
 the best you can do is use some authorization mechanism like Basic Auth or any that suit your need 
 and allow only those which are successfully authenticate according to your need

This are the approach what I flet off and as of now I don't have  any other approach :)

Hope this help